# Consecutive parallel computation with very low workload per invocation

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, real-time, thread-synchronization

Lets suppose i want to compute the methods `A` and `B` in the following example in parallel:

```
while (true)
{
   int state = NextState();

   int a = A(state);
   int b = B(state);

   ImportantMethod(a, b);
}
```

`NextState` can not be computed ahead of time in this example.
As you can see the arguments of the methods `A` and `B` are dependent on the state. The resulting values `a` and `b` are used to call the `ImportantMethod` which has to be called every iteration.

This requires the multithreading code to call `A` and `B` in parallel and wait for their result inside a single iteration. It is not possible to combine consecutive iterations to create a greater workload.

`ImportantMethod` is used in a real time application and is currently called too infrequently.
The methods `A` and `B` have quite a small workload. Roughly about 10 multiplications and 2 trigonometric functions (sin, cos), just to bring that into perspective.
`A` and `B` are the bottleneck though, `ImportantMethod` just requires the loop to be extremely fast.

I have considered using two threads for `A` and `B` and wake them up every iteration using a condition variable. But considering the small workload, i fear that the overhead of waking up the threads and waiting for their result is larger then the computation itself. I could also try using busy waiting with a boolean flag without any synchronization. That would hog the cpu really well, but that would be acceptable.

I have simplified the problem a lot and i don't think i can create a test application that would give me accurate performance metrics that would be comparable to what the real application would have. Implementing that in the real application is going to be really complicated though, so i would like to gain more knowledge before attempting that.

Therefore i would like to ask if someone has experience with these types of problems. Particularly with very frequent thread wakeups and synchronization.

Can busy waiting be favorable over notifying with a condition variable?
Are there any other methods to synchronize multiple threads that i have not considered yet which might be better suitable?

Comment: Me personally I would try and see if I can get `A` and `B` to be inlined.  If they are inlined then the compiler could add some vectorization or other techniques to leverage the processor better.

Comment: The point of being multithreaded is to process things in parallel. If you use two parallel processes to compute things sequentially, you essentially just add useless overhead to your processing. Can you create a thread that does `A()` and `B()`, and fill a list of results that you can then send to `ImportantMethod()`?

Comment: @NathanOliver `A` and `B` are not 'flat' methods and call other methods themselves. I do not think that i can get them inlined unfortunately.

Comment: @MartinVéronneau `A` and `B` can be computed independently. So there is a point in doing that at the same time with multiple cores. As i stated in my question, i can not increase the workload by combining multiple iterations of the loop.

Comment: This is a pretty tough situation, in particular because the cost of A and B is so small. It may not be possible to safely parallelize this workload without actually slowing it down. Bear in mind that modern process are "superscalar", meaning that multiple independent operations can happen at once on a single core. If you want to try to get it working in multiple threads, I'd try pinning threads to specific processors and using some barrier that spins for a certain number of iterations and then falls back to waiting on a condition variable.

Comment: @peteigel Yes, i am aware that this is really difficult and that performance gains are only to be expected when done right, if at all. That is why i am hesitant on implementing something just yet. Pinning to specific cores might help a little actually. Regarding the spinning barrier (busy wait) and condition variable fallback, i think i would go with a single synchronization technique only. The more i think about it, the more i think that busy waiting might possibly be the fastest. But i dont really know how condition variables are working under the hood.

Comment: On linux at least, `std::condition_variable` is implemented using `pthread_cnd_*`, but the critical detail here is that if a thread calls `std::condition_variable::wait()` it will sleep and the core will likely be context switched by to a different thread the OS. The issue with busy waiting is you may lose forward progress, because there is the OS's scheduler doesn't know that the thread is waiting. Consider the case where the system only has one core, the scheduler would have to essentially guess when to switch out a thread that is spinning the thread it is waiting on.

Comment: @peteigel Regarding the context switch. There is probably performance lost when switching back and forth. So it is beneficial to stop that from happening right? Can a busy wait accomplish that? Lets pretend the application will always have multiple physical cores available and that completely blocking a core, as horrible as it sounds, is acceptable. In my head, busy waiting appears to be not that bad under those circumstances.

Comment: Exactly. The issue is there is no simple way to guarantee that happens. Thread affinity may help, but my understanding is that the scheduler is free to ignore any hints you give it. After all, your process is probably just one of many running on the system. I have to use spinlocks in some kernel contexts for my day job, and they are kinda a nightmare.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195096/discussion-between-peteigel-and-mario-dekena).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i did some reasearch now. Maybe my results are going to be interesting for someone.
Keep in mind that some parts of the code below are windows specific (thread affinity and sleep to be precise).

So it looks like you can make really small workloads faster in parallel. But it requires to basically stall some (or all) cores using busy waiting. I could not archieve any speedup otherwise. It is also really important to set thread affinity so that the threads are executed on specific cores. In my tests, not doing that resulted again in slower speed then the sequential counterpart.

What i came up with is the following:

1. Set main thread affinity to a specific core
2. Spawn N worker threads and set those affinities to different cores as well
3. Busy wait in worker threads until a job for computation arrives
4. Use the main thread to assign jobs to worker threads and also do kind of a busy loop to check if any worker thread finished the execution

This results in all participating cores (including the main thread core) to be maxed out at 100% for the time of the computations. The worker threads are not terminating between consecutive parallel calls to save thread start overhead.

It should be noted that at least on windows, you have to wait some time in order for windows to properly move the threads to the requested cores. I did that using sleep. The following image shows my cpu usage during the test (60s).

[image: CPU usage during 60s in percent (8 logical cores)]

I have marked a few positions on the graph of the first core:

1. Windows moved all worker threads to their specific cores. Core#0 is not occupied anymore.
2. The task scheduler is started on Core#0 and the parallel computation has begun.
3. The task scheduler is finished and all other cores are going back to normal as well.
4. Sequential computation has started
5. Sequential computation is done

---

I have tested the timings with two different degrees of parallelism:

---

32 tasks (essentially up to 7 in parallel, the image above is captured during this test):

parallel:   2.7s

sequential: 7.1s

---

2 tasks (2 in parallel, other cores busy waiting (wasted)):

parallel:   0.365s

sequential: 0.464s

---

As you can see, there is some speedup even on the 2 tasks one. It is not half the time but considering the small workload it is not bad i guess. I am actually quite happy, that the high parallelism one performed really well. Keep in mind that the workload is still really small and after all tasks are completed, everything is synced before starting the next iteration.
The tradeoff is, that all participating cores are completely blocked as long as parallel computations can happen.

For anyone interested, here is my testing code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "windows.h"

//Object that can compute something to simulate workload
class ComputeObject
{
public:
  float A;
  float B;
  float C;

  void Compute()
  {
    //Do some calculations that approximately match the small workload
    C = float(sin(A)) + float(cos(B));
    C = C * A + atan2(A, B);
    C /= A + B;
  }
};

//Stores some information for the worker thread that is responsible for this task
struct Task
{
  ComputeObject* ComputeObject = nullptr; //the current compute object
  bool AssignedFlag = false; //flag that specifies if the compute object has a valid object
  std::thread WorkerThread; //the thread
};

//Pointer to an array of Task
Task* Tasks;

//Number of Cpus (logical cores) and number of worker tasks
int NumCpus;
int NumTask;

//Flag, that is used to stop the workers when computation is done
bool WorkersRunning;

//Main function for each worker
void TaskWorker(const int workerIndex)
{
  //Assign the worker to a specific logical core.
  //Skip the first one, because the scheduler is going to block that one.
  SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(), 1 << (workerIndex + 1));

  //Get pointer to task struct for current worker
  const auto task = Tasks + workerIndex;
  while (WorkersRunning)
  {
    while (!task->AssignedFlag && WorkersRunning); //Wait as long as no valid ComputeObject is set or the workers are stopped.
    if (!WorkersRunning) break; //Get out of the loop when workers are stopped.
    task->ComputeObject->Compute(); //Do computation
    task->AssignedFlag = false; //Invalidate current ComputeObject, so that a new one can be assigned from the scheduler
  }
}

//The scheduler runs on the main thread and constantly checks whether workers are finished with their ComputeObject and assigns new ones
void TaskScheduler(ComputeObject* computeObjects, const int numComputeObjects)
{
  const auto computeObjectsStart = computeObjects;
  const auto computeObjectsEnd = computeObjects + numComputeObjects;
  const auto tasksStart = Tasks;
  const auto tasksEnd = Tasks + NumTask;

  auto currentComputeObject = computeObjectsStart;
  auto currentTask = tasksStart;

  //as long as there are still ComputeObjects to be processed
  while (currentComputeObject != computeObjectsEnd)
  {
    if (!currentTask->AssignedFlag) //if current task has no valid ComputeObject yet
    {
      currentTask->ComputeObject = currentComputeObject++; //assign new computeObject and advance
      currentTask->AssignedFlag = true; //set flag to signal that a ComputeObject has been assigned
    }

    currentTask++; //advance to the next task
    if (currentTask == tasksEnd) currentTask = tasksStart; //go back to the first task if the last task was reached
  }
}

int main()
{
  //get number of logical cores
  NumCpus = int(std::thread::hardware_concurrency());
  NumTask = NumCpus - 1; //first one is this thread and is going to be blocked by the scheduler
  Tasks = new Task[NumTask];


  const auto numParallelWork = 32; //number of computations that can be done in parallel
  const int numInvocations = 1e6; //number of invocations for time measurement

  //create ComputeObjects array and compute start/end pointers
  const auto computeObjects = new ComputeObject[numParallelWork];
  const auto computeObjectsStart = computeObjects;
  const auto computeObjectsEnd = computeObjects + numParallelWork;

  //fill ComputeObjects with random data
  for (auto computeObject = computeObjectsStart; computeObject < computeObjectsEnd; computeObject++)
  {
    computeObject->A = float(rand()) / RAND_MAX;
    computeObject->B = float(rand()) / RAND_MAX;
  }

  //set workers running
  WorkersRunning = true;

  //spawn workers
  for (auto i = 0; i < NumTask; i++)
    Tasks[i].WorkerThread = std::thread(TaskWorker, i);

  //put this thread to first logical core
  SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(), 1 << 0);

  //wait 20s to allow windows to actually move the threads to the specified cores
  //monitor task manager to ensure windows actually did that
  Sleep(20000);

  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start, end;
  std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed;



  start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); //start time measurement

  //invoke task scheduler a few times
  for (auto i = 0; i < numInvocations; i++)
    TaskScheduler(computeObjects, numParallelWork);

  end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); //end time measurement
  elapsed = end - start;
  std::cout << "parallel: " << elapsed.count() << "s" << std::endl;


  //stop workers and wait for all threads
  WorkersRunning = false;
  for (auto i = 0; i < NumTask; i++) Tasks[i].WorkerThread.join();


  //wait 10 seconds just for good measures
  Sleep(10000);


  start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); //start time measurement

  //invoke sequential loop a few times
  for (auto i = 0; i < numInvocations; i++)
    for (auto computeObject = computeObjectsStart; computeObject < computeObjectsEnd; computeObject++)
      computeObject->Compute();

  end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); //end time measurement
  elapsed = end - start;
  std::cout << "sequential: " << elapsed.count() << "s" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Interesting work (found due to the notification in chat room). However I'm not sure about "busy wait in workers". Busy waiting seems only useful in lockfree paradigms (and even there exponential backoff is often advised) and lockfree sort of excels in low-latency situations. Since this is CPU-bound tasks, I do doubt that the situation calls for it. Then again, if you can afford the cooling bill, I guess it should work well.

Comment: @sehe This is a low-latency situation. I just tried my worker test with condition variables and wait/notify to signal the workers instead of busy waiting. The parallel code took 39.5s instead of the 2.7s with busy wait. If there is a way around busy wait, it is not condition variables. As someone allready mentioned in the comments, i  also do think that context switching from the os has to be avoided at all costs.

Comment: That's a huge difference. Note that contrasting these measurements does NOT imply that the application requires low-latency. It mostly shows that there is excessive synchronization (exemplified by the lock contention). In fact so much so, that I would I would have questions about the design (can you share less data? I'm a bit confused, as if you think about processors affinity, surely you have given data locality and sharing ample thought already).

Comment: Not trying to critique, just sharing ideas here. Indeed, if "at all cost" includes the data center cooling bill, you might be done with the work. Good enough, and all that.
(Oh, and just to be very clear: When I say that your example measurments do NOT imply the need for low-latency, I'm aware that that also does NOT imply the opposite. It's just not a strong argument for that need)

Comment: @sehe Yeah it looked like i justified low-latency with my measurements. But actually i wanted to say that in fact low-latency is requiered. Also i have done more measurements..., as a seperate argument ;) This is a realtime signal processing application where some methods need to be called in sequence while some parts can be theoretically done in parallel. The results of a single iteration need to be available immediately as they arrive (therefore low-latency). If that would not be a constraint, it would've been easy to just do some more iterations inside the threads to increase the workload.

Answer (score 2):

For a baseline for the synchronization overhead, you could start the first `A` computation with [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) (as it is only a small code change), and measure the overall speed impact (compared to the sequential code).

Before:

```
int a = A(state);
int b = B(state);
ImportantMethod(a, b);
```

After:

```
#include <future>

auto a = std::async(std::launch::async, A, state);
int b = B(state);
ImportantMethod(a.get(), b);
```

However, with the operations that you describe (10 multiplications, plus two sin/cos operations), I doubt that it will be an improvement. I am assuming that you already use some optimized sin/cos implementation (precomputed tables could also be worth trying).

Note that today's CPUs already do a lot of parallel computations under the hood, even for single-threaded code. If `A` and `B` are simple functions, the compiler should have lots of potential for optimization (e.g., vectorization).

The costs of synchronization operations (which you cannot avoid once you start using threads) can be significant. Both threads would have to synchronize on the memory of the `state` object. For transferring the result of `A` (or `B`) from one thread to the other, you can use atomic operations in this case. If you directly poll for it, you would need to initialize it with an illegal value, so you can detect when it was written. Otherwise, you need to additionally set some flag.

I doubt that the synchronization overhead can be made smaller than the costs of directly computing the value.

Comment: +1 for the easy async test. I added that to the code and while there are no performance gains, there is at least no performance lost. It suprised me a little but i double checked, and the async code is active for sure. That means it might be possible to speed things up when done right.

Comment: @MarioDekena: Did you specify `std::launch::async` when you called `std::async`? It's really easy to call `std::async`, but end up with `std::launch::deferred`, so it ends up running in the same thread (in which case, we fully expect essentially no change in performance).

Comment: @JerryCoffin i called std::async witht the first computation, then started the next computation wihout any threading and after that querried the result from std::async with get().

Comment: Yes, but when you called `std::async`, what did you pass as the first parameter?

Comment: @JerryCoffin Oh i see. I should've read the std::async doc more carefully. But as you said i guess its easy to get that one wrong. I explicitly called for launch::async and things are in fact a lot slower now. I dont have timings but it is about 2 times slower at least. Thank you for pointing that out, another mistake i am not going to make in the future!

Comment: @JerryCoffin Good observation. I left that out in my original answer, but an example would have helped. For future readers, I added some code to make it clear how it is intended.